# Send parameters to php with ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a html select list that I want to use to filter data in an li list. When user selects a list option the li list gets filtered based on the selection. all this data is stored in database. What I am trying to do is on change event in jquery check the value of selected option and then send that data to the server to use as a parameter for a query to the database.

HTML:

```
<select id="universeList">
   <option data-id="1">DC</option>
   <option data-id="2">Marvel</option>
</select>

<ul id="#heroesList">
  <li>Superman</li>
  <li>Iron Man</li>
  <li>SpiderMan</li>
  <li>Captain America</li>
  <li>Hulk</li>
  <li>Batman</li>
  <li>Flash</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on("ready", function() {

  //ajax call to populate dropdown
   $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getUniverseList.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(results) {
            console.log(results);
            $.each(results, function(index, result) {
                console.log(result);

                $('#universeList').append('<option data-id="'+result.universeID+'">'+result.universe+'</option>');


            });
        }
    });

    //ajax call populate heroes list
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getheroesList.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(results) {
            console.log(results);
            $.each(results, function(index, result) {
                console.log(result);

                $('#heroesList').append('<li data-id="'+result.heroesID+'">'+result.heroes+'</li>');


            });
        }
    });

$(document).on('change', '#universeList', function(){
    var universeSel = $('#universeList option:selected').data('id');
    $('#heroesList li').each( function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });

    console.log(manikinSel);
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"getheroesFilter.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: ( {name: universeSel} ),
        cache: false,
        success: function(results) {

            console.log(results);


    }

});

});

});
```

PHP:

```
<?php   

//db information

$mid = $_POST['manikinSel'];


$sql = "Select universeID, heroesID From heroesmanikins bm 
    INNER JOIN heroesList b 
    ON bm.heroesId=b.heroesId
    INNER join heroessList m
    ON bm.universeID=m.universeId
    WHERE heroesID=`$mid`
    ";


 try {
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $dbh->query($sql);  
$stmt->execute();
$employee = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$dbh = null;
echo  json_encode($employee) ; 
} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
}

?>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/am1yyzb4/2/)

I am using ID to match the tables and have ID as a data attribute to the option list. I want to send the ID for Universe back to php so it can be used to query matching ID's from the db tables.

I cannot figure out why my 'data: ( {name: universeSel} )' is not sending the data to the server.

Comment: making GET request and looking for $_POST at server

Comment: Thank for pointing that out. It still doesn't solve my issue though. I have tried it multiple way but it seems like the parameters never get sent to the server.

Comment: You are sending the parameter as `name` and trying to read it as `manikinSel`

Comment: @charlietfl @caeth thank you. Def solved some of my issues. Can i reference `$mid` in my where clause like I am doing in this code?